# What is the geometrical significance of the derivative of $f(x)-f(-x)$?

Tags: calculus

If $f$ is a differentiable function of one real variable, then we can understand the nature of $f$ from its derivative. If we consider the function $f_o=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$, then what is the nature of function at $x$ when $f'_o(x)>0$?

Comment: $f_0'(x)= \frac {f'(x) +f'(-x)}2$ (use the chain rule for $[f(-x)]' = -f'(-x)$).

So $f_0'(x) >0$ means $f'(x) > -f'(-x)$  which means, so far as I can tell that $f(x)$ is  increasing or decreasing  at a greater rate  at $x$ than it was decreasing or increasing at $-x$.

Comment: If it were the case that $f_0'(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$ (which is *NOT* what was asked) then the function would be lopsided with the graph to the right of the y-axis having more pronounced values than the left.  $f=e^x$ would be a perfect example but it clearly isn't the only one.  $f(x) = x^3$ if $x \ge 0$ and $f(x)=x^2$ if $x\le 0$ is another such.